# convert text file of bits to binary file

Tags: linux, bash, binary-files, xxd

I have a file `instructions.txt` with the contents:

```
00000000000000000000000000010011
00000010110100010010000010000011
00000000011100110000001010110011
00000000011100110000010000110011
00000000011100110110010010110011
00000000000000000000000000010011
```

How can I create a binary file `instructions.bin` of the same data as `instructions.txt`. In other words the `.bin` file should be the same 192 bits that are in the `.txt` file, with 32 bits per line. I am using bash on Ubuntu Linux. I was trying to use `xxd -b instructions.txt` but the output is way longer than 192 bits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

oneliner to convert 32-bit strings of ones and zeros into corresponding binary:

```
$ perl -ne 'print pack("B32", $_)' < instructions.txt > instructions.bin
```

what it does:

- `perl -ne` will iterate through each line of input file provided on STDIN (`instructions.txt`)
- `pack("B32", $_)` will take a string list of 32 bits (`$_` which we just read from STDIN), and convert it to binary value (you could alternatively use `"b32"` if you wanted ascending bit order inside each byte instead of descending bit order; see `perldoc -f pack` for more details)
- `print` would then output that converted value to STDOUT, which we then redirect to our binary file `instructions.bin`

verify:

```
$ hexdump -Cv instructions.bin
00000000  00 00 00 13 02 d1 20 83  00 73 02 b3 00 73 04 33  |...... ..s...s.3|
00000010  00 73 64 b3 00 00 00 13                           |.sd.....|
00000018

$ xxd -b -c4 instructions.bin
00000000: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00010011  ....
00000004: 00000010 11010001 00100000 10000011  .. .
00000008: 00000000 01110011 00000010 10110011  .s..
0000000c: 00000000 01110011 00000100 00110011  .s.3
00000010: 00000000 01110011 01100100 10110011  .sd.
00000014: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00010011  ....
```

Answer (score 8):

Adding the `-r` option (reverse mode) to `xxd -b` does not actually work as intended, because xxd simply does not support combining these two flags (it ignores `-b` if both are given). Instead, you have to convert the bits to hex yourself first. For example like this:

```
( echo 'obase=16;ibase=2'; sed -Ee 's/[01]{4}/;\0/g' instructions.txt ) | bc | xxd -r -p > instructions.bin
```

Full explanation:

- The part inside the parentheses creates a `bc` script. It first sets the input base to binary (2) and the output base to hexadecimal (16). After that, the `sed` command prints the contents of `instructions.txt` with a semicolon between each group of 4 bits, which corresponds to 1 hex digit. The result is piped into `bc`.
- The semicolon is a command separator in `bc`, so all the script does is print every input integer back out (after base conversion).
- The output of `bc` is a sequence of hex digits, which can be converted to a file with the usual `xxd -r -p`.

Output:

```
$ hexdump -Cv instructions.bin
00000000  00 00 00 13 02 d1 20 83  00 73 02 b3 00 73 04 33  |...... ..s...s.3|
00000010  00 73 64 b3 00 00 00 13                           |.sd.....|
00000018
$ xxd -b -c4 instructions.bin
00000000: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00010011  ....
00000004: 00000010 11010001 00100000 10000011  .. .
00000008: 00000000 01110011 00000010 10110011  .s..
0000000c: 00000000 01110011 00000100 00110011  .s.3
00000010: 00000000 01110011 01100100 10110011  .sd.
00000014: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00010011  ....
```

Comment: Sorry, there's still an endianness bug in this. Working on fixing it!

Comment: Actually, it's fine. I was confused earlier by using the wrong output width in the last xxd command.

Comment: I've tested the script and it works but outputs: `(standard_in) 1: syntax error`. Can you explain what `syntax error` it is referring to or why this occurs? Does this happen on your machine too?

Answer (score 2):

My [original answer](https://superuser.com/a/1365267/707676) was incorrect - `xxd` cannot accept either `-p` or `-r` with `-b`...

Given that the other answers are workable, and in the interest of "*another way*", how about the following:

#### Input

```
$ cat instructions.txt
00000000000000000000000000010011
00000010110100010010000010000011
00000000011100110000001010110011
00000000011100110000010000110011
00000000011100110110010010110011
00000000000000000000000000010011
```

#### Output

```
$ hexdump -Cv < instructions.bin
00000000  00 00 00 13 02 d1 20 83  00 73 02 b3 00 73 04 33  |...... ..s...s.3|
00000010  00 73 64 b3 00 00 00 13                           |.sd.....|
00000018
```

---

Bash pipeline:

```bsh
cat instructions.txt \
    | tr -d $'\n' \
    | while read -N 4 nibble; do 
        printf '%x' "$((2#${nibble}))"; \
      done \
    | xxd -r -p \
    > instructions.bin
```

- `cat` - unnecessary, but used for clarity
- `tr -d $'\n'` - remove all newlines from the input
- `read -N 4 nibble` - read *exactly* 4× characters into the `nibble` variable
- `printf '%x' "$((2#${nibble}))"` convert the nibble from binary to 1× hex character

  - `$((2#...))` - convert the given value from base 2 (binary) to base 10 (decimal)
  - `printf '%x'` - format the given value from base 10 (decimal) to base 16 (hexadecimal)
- `xxd -r -p` - reverse (`-r`) a plain dump (`-p`) - from hexadecimal to raw binary

---

Python:

```bsh
python << EOF > instructions.bin
d = '$(cat instructions.txt | tr -d $'\n')'
print(''.join([chr(int(d[i:i+8],2)) for i in range(0, len(d), 8)]))
EOF
```

- An unquoted [heredoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Unix_shells) (`<< EOF`) is used to get content into the Python code

  - This is not efficient if the input becomes large
- `cat` and `tr` - used to get a clean (one-line) input
- `range(0, len(d), 8)` - get a list of numbers from 0 to the end of the string `d`, stepping 8× characters at a time.
- `chr(int(d[i:i+8],2))` - convert the current slice (`d[i:i+8]`) from binary to decimal (`int(..., 2)`), and then to a raw character (`chr(...)`)
- `[ x for y in z]` - [list comprehension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension)
- `''.join(...)` - convert the list of characters into a single string
- `print(...)` - print it

Comment: Note: in many shells `|` at the end of a line works like a backslash: the command continues to the next line. This way you can get rid of few backslashes. I'm not sure if using pipe symbols after LFs was your informed decision. I'm mentioning the other way in case you didn't know.

Comment: I didn't know, thanks! I do like breaking the pipeline into logical lines, and having the pipes `|` (or redirects `>`, boolean operators `&&`, etc...) explicitly at the front for visibility / clarity... perhaps a stylistic / preference thing.

Comment: After some thoughts I may start using this style because one can tell the two lines are connected, by examining *any* of them. If `|` is at the end, the next line may look like a standalone command, it may be confusing. This is why I thought the style might be your informed decision.

Comment: Awesome, let me know how it goes :-)

Comment: It's going [well](https://superuser.com/a/1367255/432690). :)

Answer (score 1):

You may as well try posting this to CodeGolf SE site, but here's my alternative Python version (just for kick challenge):

```
python -c "import sys,struct;[sys.stdout.buffer.write(struct.pack('!i',int(x,2)))for x in sys.stdin]" \
< input.txt > output.bin
```

Assuming `input.txt` contains your data, and it is formatted to 32 characters per line.

This uses Python 3 `struct` package and writing / reading to stdin / out.  (In Python 2 it would've been shorter).

Answer (score 0):

binary files don't separate lines with new line characters. Binary files don't have delimiters; it's just the one file with a bunch of 0 and 1, stored on some device arranged in sectors controlled by file allocation table or similar mapping to give it meaning.

You may either convert the text file as is, to binary resulting in 192 bits (24 bytes) or add a newline character after each 32 bit sequence to give a file with 6 extra bytes.

Code below gives you a 192 bit file, as requested:

```
for x in $(cat file.txt); 
do s=${x:0:32}; 
echo $(printf '%08X' "$((2#$s))"); 
done | xxd -r -p > file.bin
```

Alternative is to read 8 bits at a time if don't want extra code for padding (4 byte lines in text file)

Tested on Ubuntu 16.04.7